# Check for special character in verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim, xstring

I would like to substitute a `>` in the beginning of each line of a `Verbatim` environment with another character. Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xstring}
\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
 \IfBeginWith{#1}{>}{t#1}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
>est  
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

This does not work. That is: it compiles with `pdflatex`, but nothing happens with the `>`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a verbatim environment some characters are made active in order to break possible ligatures. The list is kept in `\verbatim@nolig@list` which is defined as

```
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\<\do\>\do\,\do\'\do\-}
```

which tells that the activated characters are `` ` ``, `<`, `>`, `,` `'`, `-`. Also the space is active, unless "visible spaces" are to be output.

Your test checks against a `>` with category code 12, so it fails. The most common trick for getting an active character is as follows: with `\lowercase` only the character code changes, not the category code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xstring}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`> % temporarily make ~ change into >
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
   \IfBeginWith{#1}{~}{t#1}{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
>est
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to substitute the `>` with `t`, you have to avoid expansion of the active `>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xstring}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`>
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
  \renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{~}
     {\StrSubstitute[1]{#1}{~}{t}}
     {#1}%
    \restoreexpandmode
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
>est
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

---

An alternative way is to use `l3regex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__hakon_line_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \hakon_change_gt:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__hakon_line_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A > } { t } \l__hakon_line_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__hakon_line_tl
 }

%% \cs_set_eq:NN \FancyVerbFormatLine \hakon_change_gt:n

\NewDocumentCommand{\removeinitialgt}{ }
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \FancyVerbFormatLine \hakon_change_gt:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\removeinitialgt]
>est
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Instead of globally changing `\FancyVerbFormatLine` I have used the `formatcom` key. Just uncomment the line above the definition of `\removeinitialgt` if you want a global redefinition.

Comment: Thank you! How can I *substitute* the `>` with `t`? I tried `\IfBeginWith{#1}{~}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{~}{t}}{#1}`.. but I get the error: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@xs@arg@ii.`

Comment: Great! This works now, but I would never imagine it would be so complicated :) Thanks again.