# How to use comma-separated argument list in Verbatim environment?

Tags: fancyvrb, active-characters

When I try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\textcolor[RGB]{255,0,0}{test}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

... I get (instead of a red "test") an unintelligible `\unhbox\voidb@x\kern,\z@,\char,‘\protect,\relax,\kern,.16667em,0\unhbox,\voidb@x,\kern,\z@,\...`

I suspect this has something to do with "active" characters ...

What do I have to do to make this work?

Ideally, this should be done by only changing things *inside* the `Verbatim` environment, because in [my use case](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/225), the environment is provided by an external template that's out of my control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're right: the comma is made active in order to break ligatures (`,,` is a ligature defined in the T1 encoded fonts).

Since this is done as part of the initialization of verbatim environments, it cannot be undone with `` codes={\catcode`,=12 } ``, but needs a different treatment (see [Check for special character in verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110430/check-for-special-character-in-verbatim-environment))

Since it's not desirable to globally redefine `\verbatim@nolig@list`, here's a “local” solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Cverbatim}% C for "commands"
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
   \def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\<\do\>\do\'\do\-}% no comma
   \fvset{commandchars=\\\{\}}%
   \begin{Verbatim}}
  {\end{Verbatim}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Cverbatim}
\textcolor[RGB]{255,0,0}{test}
\end{Cverbatim}
\end{document}
```

However, if you don't plan needing to break the `,,` ligature in your verbatim texts, just

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\<\do\>\do\'\do\-}% no comma
\makeatother
```

in the preamble will do.

If you have control on how the verbatim text is written by your auxiliary program, you can do with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\verbatimtextcolor}{o>{\SplitArgument{2}{/}}mm}{%
  \makeverbatimtextcolor#2{#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeverbatimtextcolor}{mmmm}{%
  \textcolor[RGB]{#1,#2,#3}{#4}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\verbatimtextcolor{255/0/0}{test}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

It would also be possible to overload `\textcolor`, but an independent macro seems better.

It is actually possible to do this without external code, provided you use very clumsy input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\def\tcRGB{\textcolor[RGB]}\expandafter\tcRGB\expandafter{\detokenize{255,0,0}}{test}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! But is there also a way to make this work by changing only things *inside* the `Verbatim` environment? In other words, is there a way to write `\textcolor[RGB]{255,0,0}{test}` without the commas?

Comment: @Matthias I'm not sure I understand; however, defining a color name is much easier.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in my use case I'm auto-generating LaTeX code with a [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) template and I want to generate arbitrarily many colors from the 24-bit range. Also, I have only control about the LaTeX code *within* the `Verbatim` environment, that's why I'm asking this strange question ... I don't care how ugly or complicated the result is, since this is auto-generated anyway.

Comment: @Matthias I added a way with a different macro that converts a specification `A/B/C` into `A,B,C` for passing it to `\textcolor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still have to make changes outside of the `Verbatim` environment in this case. I could also simply define such a command `\newcommand{\textcolorRGB}[3]{\textcolor[RGB]{#1,#2,#3}}` and use `\textcolorRGB{255}{0}{0}{test}`. Still, it would be much better for my use case if I could do that without changes outside of the `Verbatim` environment. Is there a way do make a comma non-active temporarily? Or some other way to write a non-active comma? Or probably something that's specific to the `\textcolor` macro (and `\colorbox`)?

Comment: @Matthias In any case you have to add code in the preamble, if you want to modify the behavior of `\textcolor` (which you have to do).

Comment: OK, If this is unavoidable, I'll have to try to change the external template. Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Matthias It *can* be avoided (see last edit); is it worthy doing? `;-)`

Comment: Perfect, you are the best! It might be ugly, but it's exactly what I need!