# Formatting lines of \VerbatimInput

Tags: xstring, fancyvrb

I have some text files I need to include in a document, preferably using `fancyvrb` or `fvextra`. I want to highlight some of the lines of these files. The exact conditions are not important here, since my issue can be reproduced by a much simplified example.

I've tried to combine `xstring` and `fancyvrb` in a way similar to [this question/answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110430/check-for-special-character-in-verbatim-environment/110433#110433) As long as I'm using the `Verbatim` environment and inline the text, everything works just fine. If I take the exact same contents from an external file and import them using `\VerbatimInput`, I get an error message. Why is that, and how can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{a}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{Verbatim}

% \VerbatimInput{test.txt}
% will produce an error: Argument of \OT1\' has an extra }
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no error if I use `filecontents*`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{a}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{Verbatim}

\VerbatimInput{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

(the file name is unimportant, I choose `\jobname.txt` to be sure of not clobbering files in the directory where I compile examples).

[image]

Note that the package `filecontents` is obsolete. Why using `filecontents` creates problems? Because you get

```
%% LaTeX2e file `vweg.txt'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `vweg' on 2022/12/13.
%%
a one
b two
a three
b four
```

which is definitely not something you want, do you?

On the other hand, a more robust way is with `expl3`:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.txt}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:n { #1 } } { a } { \textcolor{red}{#1}} {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{Verbatim}

\VerbatimInput{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left `filecontents` so you see that no error is raised.

---

An extended version to cope with more cases:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.txt}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}{m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \str_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    { a } { \textcolor{red}{#1} }
    { b } { \textit{#1} }
    { \c_percent_str } { \textcolor{green!70!blue}{#1} }
   }
  {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
a one
b two
a three
b four
\end{Verbatim}

\VerbatimInput{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not aware of the comment generated by filecontents, thank you for the hint. However, the actual file may contain really anything - I have very little control over what characters and character sequences might occur. I'll try the expl3 solution...

Comment: @vwegert It's a common problem with `xstring` that it performs full expansion, which in the case of `'` in verbatim mode fails. With the `expl3` code we're just examining the first character on the line.

Comment: @vwegert I added an extended version to do matching with more characters.