# Formatting lines of fvextra input -- problems with line breaks

Tags: expl3, fancyvrb, fvextra

I'm trying to integrate [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668363/21841) into my document. While it mostly works, I have run into a new issue. I'm using `fvextra` because I need the line break control. Unfortunately, once a line break occurs, the formatting doesn't work any more, even though I've exchanged `\FancyVerbFormatLine` for `\FancyVerbFormatText`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\FancyVerbFormatText}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:n { #1 } } { a } { \textcolor{red}{#1}} {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fvset{breaklines}
\begin{Verbatim}
a one
b two
a three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three 
b four
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Update: As far as I've been able to find out, the redefined command appears to be executed twice: once with the parameters

```
a\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three
```

and then once more with the parameters

```
\FancyVerbBreakStart a\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\ three\FancyVerbBreakStop
```

I assume that the result of the second invocation is used and that the additional `\FancyVerbBreakStart` is derailing the comparison. How would I handle this situation?

Comment: [This picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q6zw.png) shows what I get. Where's precisely the problem?

Comment: @egreg That is what I would like to get as well. On two separate installations I'm currently using, the third (wrapped) line stays black.

Comment: I have fvextra 2022/11/30 v1.5

Comment: @egreg Updating the package fixed the issue for my MWE. Now I have run into the issue that my actual document uses `breakanywhere`, and that still has this issue. I'll try to work without `breakanywhere`...